# Annihilator of a finitely generated $K[x]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose $Q$ is a finitely generated $K[x]$-module for some field $K$. I want to show that $\mathrm{ann}_{K[x]}(q) = r(x)K[x]$ for some $r(x) \in K[x]$ and for all $q \in Q$.

So, I already showed one inclusion, i.e., $r(x)K[x] \subset\mathrm{ann}_{K[x]}(q)$. I can't get the other side that is for $m(x) \in \mathrm{ann}_{Q[x]}(m)$ we have $s(x) = r(x)q(x)$, i.e $\mathrm{ann}_{Q[x]}(q) \subset g(x)Q[x]$.

Comment: Your use of quantifiers is unclear. Do you need $r(x)$ to be valid for all $q$, or $r(x)$ could depend on $q$? Note that the second case is trivial, while the first one fails in general.

Comment: the first one is what I am after ! i.e for all  non-zero $q \in Q$ the equality above holds.

Comment: Well, in this case the statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two kinds of annihilator. If $R$ is a ring (commutative for simplicity), $M$ is a module and $x\in M$, then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)&=\{r\in R:rx=0\}
\\
\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)&=\{r\in R:rx=0, \text{ for all }x\in M\}
\end{align}
It's easy to see that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$ is an ideal of $R$ and that
$$
\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)=\bigcap_{x\in M}\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)
$$
is an ideal as well.

However, in general it's not true that, for $x,y\in M$ both nonzero,
$$
\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)=\operatorname{Ann}_R(y)
$$
For instance, suppose $r^2y=0$ but $x=ry\ne 0$. Then $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$  *properly* contains $\operatorname{Ann}_R(y)$, because $r\in\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$, but $r\notin\operatorname{Ann}_R(y)$.

The example is quite easy to make: consider an element $r\in R$ such that $r\notin(r^2)$ and $r^2\ne0$ (every non zero and non invertible element would suffice, if $R$ is a domain); then consider
$$
M=R/(r^2)
$$
The element $1+(r^2)$ has $(r^2)$ as its annihilator, whereas $r+(r^2)$ as $(r)$ as its annihilator, but $(r)\ne (r^2)$.

In the case when $R=K[x]$, with $K$ a field, every ideal is principal, so for each $q\in Q$, $\operatorname{Ann}_{K[x]}(q)=(f(x))=f(x)K[x]$, for some polynomial $f$. But there's no reason for a single $f$ generate the annihilator of every nonzero element of $Q$, because of the example above.

You may want to prove that if a nonzero finitely generated module $M$ has the property that $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$ is the same for all nonzero $x\in M$, then $M\cong (K[x]/I)^n$, where $I$ is a prime ideal of $K[x]$ (so either $0$ or generated by an irreducible polynomial).

Comment: just a quick question how did you go from (f(x)) = f(x)K[x]  ?

Comment: @L33ter It's just alternative notation.

Comment: well, there is something I am confused about well what prevents us from doing same argument again for the other annihilator ?

Comment: @L33ter The polynomial $f$ depends on $q$, of course.

Comment: Alright ok good I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be true.

Let $Q = \dfrac{K[X]}{(X)} \times \dfrac{K[X]}{(X^2)}$.

Then $\mathrm{ann}((1,0))=(X)$ and $\mathrm{ann}((0,1))=(X^2)$.

Comment: The property holds if $Q$  is cyclic.

Comment: @user26857, that's exactly my point with this example.